# c# \ not able to load user control from another user control button

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I am testing this code on a c# windows form application. Here is the test I am doing.

[image]

Panel1 has a "p1Button". 
"UserControl1" has a "uc1Button"
Clicked on "p1Button" to load "UserControl1" in Panel1
I am unable to find panel2 when I do click event on "uc1Button"

is it possible or any suggestions?

// Form1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void p1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!panel1.Controls.Contains(UserControl1.Instance))
            {
                panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl1.Instance);
                UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
            else
            {
                UserControl1.Instance.BringToFront();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// UserControl1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        private static UserControl1 _instance;
        public static UserControl1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance==null)
                {
                    _instance = new UserControl1();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void uc1Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

// UserControl2.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class UserControl2 : UserControl
    {
        private static UserControl2 _instance;
        public static UserControl2 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    _instance = new UserControl2();
                }
                return _instance;
            }
        }
        public UserControl2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your user controls are singleton , why? You need to learn about events and delegates and event handlers...

Comment: As others have already mentioned that it is of no use to make them singleton,
I would suggest  to read life cycle of controls, and a bit of in depth.
Initialize method is called via constructor
So now if you have singleton, ctor would be called once.

And hence no layout would happen.

Next question you should be asking is where is the layout code,

Answer to that is in class declaration
'partial class'

Read about all these

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not set controls as singletons.
Second of all you have to be aware parent-children boundings.

Your parent is Form. Form has two childrens - the panels. Panel 1 has other two childrens - your usercontrol and a button. Your usercontrol has other children - the button.

So if you want to put something on panel two from usercontrol1 you have at least two options:

1. The bad way.
   This is **the bad way** and you should not do this as it stricly binds and couples your usercontrol with your form. 
   You should get parent from your user control (which is panel), then get parent from this panel (which is the form) and then look the other panel.
2. The good way.
   Simple and good. Add event handler to your usercontrol, for example:

   public UserControl1: UserControl
   {
      public event EventHandler ButtonClicked;
   }

and then in your buttonclick in userControl:

```
ButtonClicked?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Then you need to sign up your main form to this handler:

```
UserControl1.ButtonClicked += (s, e) =>
{
    //show usercontrol2 on your panel.
}
```

You should read more about delegates and events in C#.